# Adding a public JS in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I have added new public javascript in meteor and loaded liked this

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.created = function() {
        $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Chart.min.js">');
    };

}
```

but I got this error in the browser console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js?dd8bac56f8fd3666d433d2285ae01e52597cc51a:372 (anonymous function)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually rely on jQuery's `$.getScript` function to asynchronously load additional JS files in my Meteor app, using a `ReactiveVar` (don't forget to `meteor add reactive-var`) to track the script availability :

HTML

```
<template name="parent">
  {{#if chartLoaded}}
    {{> child}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="child"}}
  {{! here we can assume the script is loaded}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.parent.created = function() {
  this.chartLoaded=new ReactiveVar(false);
  var template=this;
  $.getScript("/js/Chart.min.js",function(){
    template.chartLoaded.set(true);
  });
};

Template.parent.helpers({
  chartLoaded:function(){
    return Template.instance().chartLoaded.get();
  }
});

Template.child.rendered=function(){
  // safely use Chart.min.js functionality
};
```

This pattern allows to load asynchronously certain scripts only when a given parent template gets rendered (such as admin stuff), and takes care of only rendering the corresponding child template when the script is done loading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still does not work. I tried to debug and see if Chart.min.js is loaded using getScript. I have put a console log like this ' $.getScript("js/Chart.min.js", function () {
            console.log("Loaded");
            template.chartLoaded.set(true);
        });
' but "Loaded" text is not display in the console.

Comment: My mistake, the correct path should be `/js/Chart.min.js` but I forgot the leading slash in my answer, this has been edited, the script needs to live in `public/js/` by the way.

Comment: thanks! it works. Is this how tedious meteor is? :( I come from rails. In rails I just put js in assets and it works and loaded.

Comment: This pattern is useful only if you want to load specific JS assets on specific routes of your app, if you simply want your JS file to be loaded on every client at startup just throw your JS file anywhere under the `client` directory.